# pass state value as props to another component es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm able to pass data around but I'm stuck here, how to pass state of `AddTodo component` to `Todos component`? Is there anything wrong with my component structure?

```
class AddTodo extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }
  onTextChanged(e){
    this.setState({text:e.target.value});
  }
  addHandler(){
    alert(this.state.text); // pass this to Todos??
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>this.onTextChanged(e)} />
        <button onClick={()=>this.addHandler()}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.data = ['write book','wash clothes','jogging'];
  }
  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
        <AddTodo/>
        <ul>
         {this.data.map((item)=><TodoItems key={item} item={item}/>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}
```

Live demo here http://jsbin.com/susadehacu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you just need to add a method in `Todos` to add an item to your list. This would then be passed into your `AddTodo` component as a prop.

**Todos**

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.data = ['write book','wash clothes','jogging'];
}

addTodo(todo) {
  // new array
  let newData = this.data.slice();
  newData.push(todo);
  this.setState({data: newData});
}

...

<AddTodo addTodo={(todo) => this.addTodo(todo)} />
```

**AddTodo**

```
addHandler(){
  this.props.addTodo(this.state.text);
}
```